# How to make component not re-render when navigating pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

In my application there is a main home page that gets loaded and there is another page (Page2.js) I can navigate to via the navbar I have implemented. The problem is that when I go to Page2.js and then go back to the main page, it will re-render all of the components on the main page. I am wondering if there is a way to check the last pathname and say if it is equal to a certain value then all of the components should stay the same?

I have tried using the shouldComponentUpdate method in the navbar (since I do not want it to change) and it is pretty faulty in that it would not read prevProps.location as a value but undefined:

```
shouldComponentUpdate = (prevProps) => {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

***App.js*** holds the code for my routing in the application:

```
// imports here

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const {location} = this.props;
        return (
            <Switch >
                <DefaultLayoutRoute exact path="/">
                    <Redirect to={HomePage}/>
                </DefaultLayoutRoute>

                <Route exact path={SIGNOUT} render={() => {
                    auth0Client.signOut();
                    window.location.href = homeRedirect;
                    return null
                }}>
                </Route>

                <Route exact path={LOGIN_SUCCESS} component={Callback}/>

                <DefaultLayoutRoute exact path={HomePage} location={location.pathname} component={HomePage}
                                    pageName="Office Production"/>

                <DefaultLayoutRoute
                    exact
                    path={AGENTRANKING}
                    component={AgentRankings}
                    pageName="Agents"
                />

                <DefaultLayoutRoute exact path={SETTINGS} component={Settings}/>
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

***Expected Result:*** To be able to navigate to Page2.js and then back to the main page with all of the components rendered the way it was unless I manually refresh

***Actual Results:*** I go back to the main page and all the components start to re-render.